# Position of icon in Leaflet Easy Button

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet, google-material-icons

I'm using Leaflet easy button on my Leaflet map:

```
<!-- Load LeafletEasyButton -->  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-easybutton@2/src/easy-button.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-easybutton@2/src/easy-button.js"></script>
```

I'm also using Google Material icons:

```
<!-- Load Google Material Icons -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
```

The goal is to create a custom button on my leaflet map like this:

```
L.easyButton('<i class="material-icons" style="font-size:18px;">gps_fixed</i>', function(){
    locateMe();
}, {position: 'bottomright'}).addTo(map);
```

It works, but icon in my custom button is positioned above button center:

[image]

How can I center the icon?

Comment: vertical aligning material icons. [check here](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/206)

Comment: Did you applied `line-height' to your CSS?

Comment: @Aswin Kumari I added ```display: inline-flex; vertical-align: middle;``` and now It is a bit too low, but still better than before. Is there any way to fine tune it?

Comment: @Mobarak Ali I did not apply 'line-height' to my CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use left/top in css code:

```
 .widget-code {
    display: block;
    height: 18px;
    left: 6px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 6px;
    width: 18px;
}
```

Comment: Good idea. padding-bottom worked for me: ```<i class="material-icons" style="font-size:18px; padding-bottom: 3px; display: inline-flex; vertical-align: middle;">gps_fixed</i>```